# Android studio not recognizing my device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, nexus-7

I know this question may sound like a reiteration of all the other similar ones, but unfortunately none of the other solutions are working.

Problems:

1.ADB doesnt show my nexus 7 (4.4.2) in devices connected.

2.When I go to search drivers from a lsit there is no Google Inc or Android there.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you can try:

1. Install universal USB Driver
2. Enable USB Debugging
3. Connect your phone as camera MTP

If this doesnt work for you,  add some information what you tried!